# How to get a JavaFX textfield value into XPath Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, javafx

So I have a JavaFX TextField, and I want to find that inputted value on a webpage using that text input. This is the code:

```
private static TextField ItemColor = new TextField();
```

And then,

```
 String color = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@data-style-name='Brick']")).getAttribute("href");
    driver.get(color);
```

Instead of 'Brick' as the value, I am trying to get the ItemColor text in there.
I have tried placing ItemColor.getText() in there, but it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated!

Edited since my code above apparently wasn't complete enough. It works until the String color = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@data-style-name='Brick']")).getAttribute("href"); line.

```
public static void supremeBot()
{   
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    String url = Category.getText();
    driver.get(url);
    while(driver.findElements(By.linkText(Item.getText())).isEmpty())
        driver.navigate().refresh();

    double starttime = (double)System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    String productlink = driver.findElement(By.linkText(Item.getText())).getAttribute("href");
    driver.get(productlink); 

    String color = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@data-style-name='Brick']")).getAttribute("href");
    driver.get(color);

    WebElement selectsize = driver.findElement(By.name("size"));
    List<WebElement> sizeoptions = selectsize.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
    for (WebElement option : sizeoptions)
    {
        if(option.getText().equals(Size.getText()))
            option.click();
    }
```

And then more code, but the error occurs on the String color - XPath line.

```
String color = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@data-style-name='Brick']")).getAttribute("href"); THIS WORKS

String color = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@data-style-name=ItemColor.getText()]")).getAttribute("href"); THIS DOESN'T WORK

String color = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@data-style-name='ItemColor.getText()']")).getAttribute("href"); THIS DOESN'T WORK
```

Comment: The error is in the [code you don't show](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks, but that is almost definitely not the answer because the code above works fine, but placing ItemColor.getText() returns an Element Not Found Exception. There also is no other code relating to these sections that would return an error (or relating to this part at all)

Comment: I have never worked with XPath but, taking a completely wild guess, I would suggest that an `ElementNotFoundException` indicates that an element with the given name could not be found.

Comment: Yes I know, and that's because it's not recognizing the ItemColor.getText() as a value from JavaFX. Rather, it is literally searching for ItemColor.getText() on the webpage, which isn't what I intend it to do. I want it to search for the value that ItemColor.getText() represents, or the value inputted into the text field.

Comment: How about you actually provide sufficient information to answer the question? Provide, as you were previously asked for, a [MCVE]. Provide the code that causes the exception (instead of the code that doesn't cause the exception). Provide the stack trace and indicate precisely which line in the code is throwing the exception (instead of making vague statements like "there is no other code ... that would return an error"). No-one can help if you post nonsense like this.

Comment: Actually, this is the code that is producing the error. I can write out my code, but it would not be of help (I will do so up above in a moment). Also, I find it unfair after explaining the issue clearly that you say "I'm posting nonsense." No wonder many new members here feel discouraged. But no worries, editing the post above.

Comment: @James_D There, I edited my nonsense question. Any help would be appreciated. If this isn't enough of my code, I would be happy to provide more.

Comment: I guess I am just being dumb today. The way I understood it was that the line `String color = ... ;` works just fine when you have the hardcoded value (`'Brick'`) in there, and that it didn't work when you tried to replace the hardcoded value with the value you retrieve from the text field. But in the block of code you posted, you say the exception is being thrown from the same line `String color = ... ;`, but you still have a hardcoded value in there. So I guess I don't really understand what it is you're asking.

Comment: It works fine when I have 'Brick' in there. It throws the exception when I try and place ItemColor.getText() in there. Your explanation of the issue was correct.

Comment: OK. So this is why I'm getting so frustrated. I don't see any line starting `String color = ...;` which references the text field. So, again, unless I'm misunderstanding something, you still haven't actually shown the actual line of code you tried to execute that generates the error. So it's not going to be very easy to tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I again edited the post with what you ask @James_D

Comment: The code you just added has the hard-coded string `"ItemColor.getText()"` (rather than an actual call to the method). Is that code exactly what you have tried?

Comment: I tried the 3 methods I added, the 1st one works and the other 2 do not. I haven't tried anything else. I am not sure what you mean by an actual call to the method. I am sorry if I am being difficult, I am new to all of this and truly want to understand my error.

Comment: For future reference, you should probably read some of the Stack Overflow help pages: [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the previously-linked How to Create a [MCVE]. No-one is going to appreciate having to squeeze enough information out of you to understand what the problem is as though they are trying to get blood from a stone. You should probably read up on some basic Java syntax, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line of code

```
String color = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@data-style-name='ItemColor.getText()']"))
    .getAttribute("href");
```

just includes `"ItemColor.getText()"` as a hardcoded String; there is no actual call to the `ItemColor.getText()` method. You need to call the method and concatenate the result of the method call in the string you pass to the `By.xpath(..)` method:

```
String color = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@data-style-name='" + ItemColor.getText()+ "']"))
    .getAttribute("href");
```

Comment: Thank you very much; this is exactly what I was looking for. I see my mistake now. I'm sorry if this post came across as nonsense.